# Proof about cross product

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I'm currently stuck with the following proof:

Show that, if c=b+ua, then a x c=a x b
    ´
(a,b,c are vectors; u is a     scalar 
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations.

Comment: Have you considered just applying the cross product with $a$ to both sides of the equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a\times c = a\times(b+ua)=a\times b + ua\times a$.

But $a\times a=0$, so $a\times c =a\times b$.